# How do I make other function calling to Wait Until My UIView is fully drawn

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, multithreading, uiview

So here's the thing:
I'm writing a demo for genetic algorithm. The demo is about using polygons to approximate an image. The process of the algorithm is like evolving generation by generation and I want to display every generation so it'll show how these polygons are evolving.
So I have a `GAView: UIView` class, it has a property called `currentDrawing` which means the current generation of polygons. 
I use BezierPath to draw those polygons.

I have a function `evolve` which gets a snapshot image from the current view and calculate the pixel errors of the image and then update the view according to the pixel errors.
So the process is like this:

`Draw the view` -> `Snapshot the View` -> `Do Calculations based on the Snapshot` -> `Change the view's property and redraw it` -> `Loops Back`

The evolve is like this:

```
func evolve() {
    let fooDrawing = currentDrawing.clone()
    fooDrawing.mutate()
    if fooDrawing.isDirty {
        generation += 1

        //This redraws the GAView because I called setNeedsDisplay in the didSet of currentDrawing
        GAView.currentDrawing = fooDrawing
        let newErrorLevel = FitnessCalculator.calculateFitnessFor(currentDrawingView: GAView)
        if newErrorLevel <= errorLevel {
            objc_sync_enter(currentDrawing)
            currentDrawing = fooDrawing
            objc_sync_exit(currentDrawing)
            errorLevel = newErrorLevel

        }
    }
}
```

So calling `evolve()` has a serious problem that the calculations is so fast and the UIView's drawing is actually not in real-time which caused the UIView to wait forever because every time it wants to redraw its currentDrawing changes. And my calculation cannot get the correct View to calculate. And iOS keeps caching those snapshots which eventually crashed Xcode.

So I'm wondering how I can make sure the calculations are executed after the view is drawn?

Comment: Do you have a way to save one-to-one pointers, between the snapshots and the calculations they should trigger? You could subclass UIView (or GAView) to send a message in viewWillAppear to a delegate, whose job it would be to trigger the appropriate calculation.

Comment: @dylanthelion thanks for the advice! I'll give it a try.

Comment: My apologies; I realized this mistake an hour later. Because you are working with a UIView, you want to override a func in the UIView lifecycle. viewWillAppear is func of UIViewController. The same pattern should work, with the correct class. Here's a link, with a simple list and description of the methods in a UIView life cycle:
http://beankhan.tistory.com/21

Comment: @dylanthelion thanks lol. Been busy all day and didn't have time to work with my project. I'll see to it when my winter vacation comes lol.